# Same MDX different return values?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

The below two `MDX` in the photos return two different values although they are almost the same , any one have clarification to help me to understand the difference ?

[image: MDX_1]

[image: MDX_2]

Comment: Hi - Please edit your question so that the code is in the question rather than screenshots.

Comment: i've never seen the CURRENTMEMBER used in a WHERE clause before - intuitively it seems pointless to me: maybe you can provide a very simple example where it makes sense to do this?

Comment: when I browse the Cube and design the report and click on DESIGN MODE it gives me the first MDX with CURRENTMEMBER in a WHERE Clause, the problem is am using internal BI tool created by my company like QLIK View and Microstrategy and when the tool tries to connect to the cube it act like the first MDX .

Comment: Are you trying to get the sum of `[Measures].[Sales Value]` for the year 2015 twice? Whether you do or don't, I think the issue has to do with the fact that the FROM clause in the first query is limited to two members, where as the second query has access to all members in the [TimeHierarchy] dimension.